# Limit results to 1 row for each group in subquery

Tags: mysql

as a result of the execution of this query, situations are possible when two rows have the same minimum price, but i still need to select one. I understand perfectly well that the standard limit cannot be dispensed with here. I do not have enough knowledge to understand from which side to approach the solution of this issue. Thank you in advance for your attension.

```
UPDATE offers t1
SET t1.deleted_at = NOW()
WHERE t1.id 
    NOT IN
    (
        SELECT f.id
        FROM (
            SELECT name, MIN(net_price) as minprice
            FROM offers
            WHERE
                supplier_id = (SELECT id FROM suppliers WHERE name = 'somename')
            group BY name
        ) 
        AS x inner join (SELECT * FROM offers) AS f ON f.name = x.name AND f.net_price = x.minprice
    )
     AND
     t1.supplier_id = (SELECT id FROM suppliers WHERE name = 'somename');
```

Comment: You can't just add `LIMIT 1` at the end, and add order to be sure to have what you want ?

Comment: @Elikill58 , I am getting an error that Limit is not supported in subqueries.
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN / ALL / ANY / SOME subquery

Comment: Oh, it's a pitty. And you can't use something like group by ?

Comment: @Elikill58, So I already use group by, I'm just in a group and need to limit result from a group to 1 row, or do you mean something else?

Comment: The issue appear on this request: `SELECT name, MIN(net_price) as minprice FROM offers` ? Oh i was thinking about the supplier one. Maybe you can add price to the group by like: `GROUP BY name, net_price`

Comment: @Elikill58   I need something like this:
`group BY name LIMIT 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234816/discussion-between-aleksandr-taran-and-elikill58).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know somehowe, but this works for me:

```
UPDATE offers t1
SET t1.deleted_at = NOW()
WHERE t1.id 
    NOT IN
    (
        SELECT f.id
        FROM (
            SELECT id, name, MIN(net_price) as minprice
            FROM offers
            WHERE
                supplier_id = (SELECT id FROM suppliers WHERE name = 'somename')
            group BY name
        ) 
        AS x inner join (SELECT * FROM offers) AS f ON f.id = x.id
    )
     AND
     t1.supplier_id = (SELECT id FROM suppliers WHERE name = 'somename');
```

Just add `id` to subquery `select` and put it on inner join `f.id = x.id`